# MySQL syntax error in SELECT query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, calendar

Hi everyone

I'm getting this syntax problem and I don't see anything wrong with my query.
I'm kind of new at SQL as I'm still an undergrad. I'd really appreciate it if you could help me with this.

This is the code:

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT event.nameevent,event.eventid
    FROM event,sub
    WHERE sub.userid=$userid AND event.eventid=sub.orgid AND 
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM startdate)=$year AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM startdate)=$month
    AND EXTRACT(DAY FROM startdate)=$list_day") 
or die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($results) >0 )
{
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($results))
    {
        $nameevent = $row['nameevent'];
        $eventid   = $row['eventid'];
        $calendar.="<a href='memberview.php?eventid=$eventid'>".$nameevent."</a>";
        $calendar.= "<br>";
    }
}
else
{
    $calendar.='you have no events today';
}
```

It returns this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND event.eventid=sub.orgid AND
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM startdate)=2010 AND EXTRACT( at line 3
```

I tested this code in a blank page and it works however when I integrate it inside the calendar page it doesn't work. Any suggestions?
I have tested **$userid, $year, $month** and **$day** and all returns a value.

Comment: Pl delete your answer and add it as comment like I did this! and more about formatting pl read http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 3):

```
mysql_query("
SELECT `event.nameevent`, `event.eventid` 
FROM `event`,`sub` 
WHERE `sub.userid`='" . $userid . "'
AND `event.eventid`=`sub.orgid` 
AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM `startdate`)='" . $year . "' 
AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM `startdate`)='" . $month . "' 
AND EXTRACT(DAY FROM `startdate`)='" . $list_day . "'
");
```

You should escape your data and DB fields.

Comment: Backtickinging '`event,sub`' will break any query... where needed, backticks should be around each individual table/column name (e.g. '`event`','`sub`'), not a single set of backticks wrapped around two different table names

Comment: i tried the new code on another page and it works however it can't store it inside $calendar.=$nameevent 

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

You'll find it useful when starting out to create a variable containing your sql statement.

```
$sql = "SELECT event.nameevent,event.eventid
   FROM event,sub
    WHERE sub.userid=$userid AND event.eventid=sub.orgid AND 
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM startdate)=$year AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM startdate)=$month
    AND EXTRACT(DAY FROM startdate)=$list_day" ; 
$results = mysql_query( $sql ) ;`
```

This affords you the ability to

```
echo $sql ;
```

onto the page, where you can

- take a close look at it
- paste the statement directly into you sql manager.

Not saying this is answering your question, but providing you with a strategy to divide and conquer PHP and SQL errors - especially common quoting errors.

Jolly useful as a sanity check that there actually is corresponding data in your database in the case of zero results.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the $userid variable contains something. If it's an empty string you'll end up with

```
SELECT event.nameevent,event.eventid
FROM event,sub
WHERE sub.userid= AND
```

And this will throw an error.